# Size of curly brackets

Tags: brackets

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{\partial\pi\left( z \right)}{\partial CAF_{ij}}}{GLOB_{j}} =&\left( \theta_{10} + \theta_{11} + \omega_{1j} \right)\{\xi\left\lbrack\theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\overbar{AF}_{j} + (\theta_{10} + \theta_{11} + \omega_{1j})CAF_{ij} + \theta_{01} + \omega_{0j}\right\rbrack \times \notag \\
&\left\lbrack 1 - \xi\left\lbrack \theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\overbar{AF}_{j}+ \left( \theta_{10} + \theta_{11} + \omega_{1j} \right)CAF_{ij} + \theta_{01} + \omega_{0j} \right\rbrack\right\rbrack\} - \notag \\
&\left( \theta_{10} + \omega_{1j} \right)\{\xi\left\lbrack\theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\overbar{AF}_{j} + (\theta_{10} + \omega_{1j})CAF_{ij} + \omega_{0j}\right\rbrack \times \notag \\
&\left\lbrack 1 - \xi\left\lbrack \theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\overbar{AF}_{j} + \left( \theta_{10} + \omega_{1j} \right)CAF_{ij} + \omega_{0j} \right\rbrack\right\rbrack\}\label{mi}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I cannot fit the size of curly brackets, which I would like to have larger to embed the content inside. Any help?

[image]

Comment: as they span over the alignment you need to choose them manually say `\biggl\{` at the start and `\biggr\}` at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you start by deleting the 11 instances of `\left` and `\right`. Next, replace both instances of `\{` and `\]}` with `\bigl\{` and `\bigr\}`, respectively.

Assuming that `AF`, `CAF`, and `GLOB` are variable names, they should probably be typeset with upright rather than math-italic letters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' env.
\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % how to display variable names
\newcommand\AF{\overbar{\vn{AF}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{mi}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\smash[b]{\frac{\frac{\partial\pi( z )}{\partial \vn{CAF}_{ij}}}{\vn{GLOB}_{j}}}
&=( \theta_{10} + \theta_{11} + \omega_{1j} )
   \bigl\{ \xi[\theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\AF _{j} + (\theta_{10} + \theta_{11} 
   + \omega_{1j})\vn{CAF}_{ij} + \theta_{01} + \omega_{0j}]   \\
&\qquad\times[ 1 - \xi[ \theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\AF _{j}+ ( \theta_{10} 
   + \theta_{11} + \omega_{1j} )\vn{CAF}_{ij} + \theta_{01} + \omega_{0j} ]] \bigr\}   \\
&\quad-( \theta_{10} + \omega_{1j} )  
   \bigl\{ \xi[\theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\AF _{j} + (\theta_{10} + 
   \omega_{1j})\vn{CAF}_{ij} + \omega_{0j}]   \\
&\qquad\times[ 1 - \xi[ \theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\AF _{j} 
   + ( \theta_{10} + \omega_{1j} )\vn{CAF}_{ij} + \omega_{0j} ]] \bigr\}
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful suggestions. I think i will use the one by Mico. And yes, they are variable names.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest here is to add `\bigl` and `\bigr` at the relevant places:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{\partial\pi\left( z \right)}{\partial CAF_{ij}}}{GLOB_{j}} =&\left( \theta_{10} + \theta_{11} + \omega_{1j} \right)\bigl\{\xi\left\lbrack\theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\overbar{AF}_{j} + (\theta_{10} + \theta_{11} + \omega_{1j})CAF_{ij} + \theta_{01} + \omega_{0j}\right\rbrack \times \notag \\
&\left\lbrack 1 - \xi\left\lbrack \theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\overbar{AF}_{j}+ \left( \theta_{10} + \theta_{11} + \omega_{1j} \right)CAF_{ij} + \theta_{01} + \omega_{0j} \right\rbrack\right\rbrack\bigr\} - \notag \\
&\left( \theta_{10} + \omega_{1j} \right)\bigl\{\xi\left\lbrack\theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\overbar{AF}_{j} + (\theta_{10} + \omega_{1j})CAF_{ij} + \omega_{0j}\right\rbrack \times \notag \\
&\left\lbrack 1 - \xi\left\lbrack \theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\overbar{AF}_{j} + \left( \theta_{10} + \omega_{1j} \right)CAF_{ij} + \omega_{0j} \right\rbrack\right\rbrack\bigr\}\label{mi}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I would also get rid of the 11 instances of `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @Mico: You're right. I only thought of avoiding adding three pairs of `\left \right`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't have `\left` in a row and the corresponding `\right` in another one. You need to use manual sizing. Anyway, most of your `\left` and `\right` do nothing.

I'd not try to cram as much as possible into each line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe} % remove from the production version

\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{mi}
\begin{split}
\lefteqn{
  \frac{1}{\mathit{GLOB}_{j}} 
  \frac{\partial\pi(z)}{\partial \mathit{CAF}_{ij}}
}\quad& \\
&=(\theta_{10} + \theta_{11} + \omega_{1j}) \\
&\qquad\cdot
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  \bigl\{&
    \xi\bigl[
      \theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\overbar{\mathit{AF}}_{j} +
      (\theta_{10} + \theta_{11} + \omega_{1j})\mathit{CAF}_{ij} +
      \theta_{01} + \omega_{0j}
    \bigl]\\
  & \cdot\bigl[
      1 - \xi[\theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\overbar{\mathit{AF}}_{j} +
      (\theta_{10} + \theta_{11} + \omega_{1j})\mathit{CAF}_{ij} +
      \theta_{01} + \omega_{0j}]
     \bigr]
   \bigr\}
   \end{aligned} \\
&\quad-
   ( \theta_{10} + \omega_{1j} ) \\
&\qquad\cdot
   \begin{aligned}[t]
   \bigl\{&
     \xi\bigl[
       \theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\overbar{\mathit{AF}}_{j} +
       (\theta_{10} + \omega_{1j})\mathit{CAF}_{ij} +
       \omega_{0j}
     \bigr] \\
   &\cdot
     \bigl[
       1 - \xi[ \theta_{00} + \eta_{1}\overbar{\mathit{AF}}_{j} +
       ( \theta_{10} + \omega_{1j} )\mathit{CAF}_{ij} + \omega_{0j} ]
     \bigr]
   \bigr\}
   \end{aligned}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]